# C# UWP - How to access page controls from another page?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way to access page controls from another page. I have some controls in my **MainPage** and i want to access Mainpage Controls **TitleTextBlock** from another page which contains list view. I want change **Mainpage TitleTextBlock.Text** when listview item selected.

I also try but TitleTextBlock.Text value doesn't change. so is there any way??

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public void ChangeTitle(string title)
{
   TitleTextBlock.Text = title;
   BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

**ContentPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   var link = (Link)e.ClickedItem;
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(WebViewPage), link);

   MainPage p = new MainPage();
   p.ChangeTitle(link.Title);
}
```

**Updated**
I solved this problem with few changes
**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public static TextBlock HeaderTitleTextBlock { get; set; }
 public static Button HeaderBackButton { get; set; }

 public MainPage()
   {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      HeaderTitleTextBlock = TitleTextBlock;
      HeaderBackButton = BackButton;

   }
```

**ContentPage.xaml.cs**

```
MainPage.HeaderTitleTextBlock.Text = link.Title;
MainPage.HeaderBackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: You are not working on the existing window, i.e, you are creating new instance of MainPage and operating on it, that will not affect the currently open MainPage, you will have to pass reference of already instantiated MainPage and operate on it.

Comment: Consider using a [view model](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uwp+viewmodel+hasaccepted%3A1)

Comment: Can you explain details, please? - shashikant_

Comment: WPF and it's followup UWP were specifically designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can apply older techniques, those miss about 90% of it's ability. If you use MVVM, the question is non-existant: Wich part of the view model you currently display does not change that the whole thing is in memory. If you need a short introduction into that pattern, I wrote something a few years back: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also make the control appear as `public` (which was the default behavior of WPF)  using `x:FieldModifier` attribute:

```
<TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="MyTextBlock" />
```

This will make the control public and it will be accessible from the other classes.

I have written a short blog post on this: http://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/06/modifying-xaml-field-visibility/

Answer (score 0):

What i've used :

```
Frame contentFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
MainPage mp =  contentFrame.Content as MainPage;
Grid grid = mp.Content as Grid;
TextBlock my_textblock = grid.FindName("my_textblock") as TextBlock;

my_textblock.Text = "Edited the TextBlock";
```

Of course, the hierarchy Frame>Page>Grid>TextBlock is the one I used in my UWP app.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is less convenient than using the field / or property, as Find name is slower and once you change the hierarchy it breaks

Comment: The one I used in my answer, or even better - creating a read only property that provides access to the named field (so that outside users cannot tamper with it).