# How can several .xaml use the same .xaml.cs class?

Tags: winui-3, winui

Is it possible that several .xaml files use the same MainPage.cs? At the moment I have several pages with separate .xaml and xaml.cs files. I want all .cs in one, so that I have easy access to all elements of all .xaml pages from MainPage.cs.

I tried the ideas from [C# UWP - How to access page controls from another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150301/c-sharp-uwp-how-to-access-page-controls-from-another-page) but weren't really lucky with it. I know MVVM but want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Can you post some example code (it's OK it doesn't work) about what you want to achieve?

Comment: @mainhar2: Move the common code to a separate class that you can reuse in other classes/views?